# `str_replace_all` numeric values in column according to named vector

Tags: r, tidyverse, str-replace

I want to use a named vector to map numeric values of a data frame column.

consider the following example:

```
df <- data.frame(year = seq(2000,2004,1), value = sample(11:15, r = T)) %>% 
    add_row(year=2005, value=1)

df
#   year value
# 1 2000    12
# 2 2001    15
# 3 2002    11
# 4 2003    12
# 5 2004    14
# 6 2005     1
```

I now want to replace according to a vector, like this one

```
repl_vec <- c("1"="apple", "11"="radish", "12"="tomato", "13"="cucumber", "14"="eggplant", "15"="carrot")
```

which I do with this

```
df %>% mutate(val_alph = str_replace_all(value, repl_vec))
```

However, this gives:

```
  #   year value     val_alph
  # 1 2000    11   appleapple
  # 2 2001    13       apple3
  # 3 2002    15       apple5
  # 4 2003    12       apple2
  # 5 2004    14       apple4
  # 6 2005     1        apple
```

since `str_replace_all` uses the first match and not the whole match. In the real data, the names of the named vector are also numbers (one- and two-digits).

I expect the output to be like this:

```
  # year value     val_alph
  # 1 2000    11     radish
  # 2 2001    13   cucumber
  # 3 2002    15     carrot
  # 4 2003    12     tomato
  # 5 2004    14   eggplant
  # 6 2005     1      apple
```

Does someone have a clever way of achieving this?

Comment: Also, for the part of your question that's about indexing into that vector `repl_vec`, try `repl_vec[as.character(df$value)]`.

Comment: @Ivo Done. Might be best to go ahead and edit the example itself, using e.g. fruits instead of numbers as the values you want to map to. (Also, make it fully reproducible by loading any packages that are needed for the code to run.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use base R's `match` instead of string matching here, since you are looking for exact whole string matches.

```r
df %>%
 mutate(value = repl_vec[match(value, names(repl_vec))])
#>   year    value
#> 1 2000   radish
#> 2 2001   carrot
#> 3 2002   carrot
#> 4 2003 cucumber
#> 5 2004 eggplant
#> 6 2005    apple
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want to do?

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(year = seq(2000,2004,1), value = sample(11:15, r = T)) %>% 
  add_row(year=2005, value=1)

repl_vec <- c("1"="one", "11"="eleven", "12"="twelve", "13"="thirteen", "14"="fourteen", "15"="fifteen")
names(repl_vec) <- paste0("\\b", names(repl_vec), "\\b")

df %>%
  mutate(val_alph = str_replace_all(value, repl_vec, names(repl_vec)))
```

which gives:

```
  year value val_alph
1 2000    14 fourteen
2 2001    12   twelve
3 2002    15  fifteen
4 2003    14 fourteen
5 2004    11   eleven
6 2005     1      one
```